# Return the last evaluated object from a file

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to return the last evaluated object from a Ruby file?

Suppose I have a file like:

```
# app.rb
def foo
  "Hello, world!"
end
foo
```

Then, I would expect something like this behavior:

```
# other_file.rb
require_relative!('foo') # => "Hello, world!"
```

Instead of the `require_relative`'s `true` returned value, we fetch the last evaluated object of the required file.

Is there a way to have a `require_relative!`-like behavior?

Comment: No, you cannot do it in a normal way. A brute force way is to read the whole file as a string and `eval` it. Otherwise, you need to write a C library yourself.

Comment: Wow... I see. Just to prevent from some exceptions, is it possible to check the syntax of such string, before to eval it?

Something like `check(s) # => true`:
`o = File.open '/app.rb'; s = o.read; eval s if check(s)`

Comment: That should be a different question (but it would be a duplicate of an already existing one). If you are really interested in that, you should ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a bad practice. Ruby files are storages of ruby code, not data.

Idiomatically you should create a Ruby file with class or module, require it and call some function from it.

```
# foo.rb
module Foo
  extend self

  def foo
    "bar"
  end
end

# irb
require 'foo'
Foo.foo
#=> bar
```

Otherwise, as @sawa mentioned, you should read file as a string and eval it. Which is idiomatically wrong.

Comment: Yes, that's not a common thing. But the way showed by @sawa is pretty much matching my needs. I just would like to add a check of the syntax before the evaluation, against the string instead of the file (I mean without `ruby -c app.rb`).